# How can I make a data frame of the unique values in an existing column?

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr

I need to make a new data frame (`col.3`) using only the occurrences in a previous column (`col.1`) that correspond to unique values in another column (`col.2`) in an existing data frame.

I need this:

```
df1
col.1   col.2     
    1    1             
    1    3             
    1    7             
    1    7            
    2    12                
    2    14   
    2    14
    2    14

 df2
 col.3
     1
     1
     1
     2
     2
```

I have tried this:

```
new.col <- cbind(df$col.1[unique(df$col.2)])
```

But it gives me a column that is both too long, and which does not include the complete set of `col.1` values

I suspect that `plyr` has a simple solution to this, but I have not figured that (or any other solution) out.

How can I achieve my desired result? Preferably using `plyr`, but `base` is fine too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `duplicated` to create a logical index and use that to subset the rows

```
df2 <- data.frame(col3. = df$col.1[!duplicated(df$col.2)])
```

Or with `subset`

```
subset(df, !duplicated(col.2), select = col.1)
```

---

Or with `dplyr`, use`distinct` on `col.2` and then `select` the 'col.1'

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   distinct(col.2, .keep_all = TRUE) %>%
   select(col.3 = col.1)
#  col.3
#1     1
#2     1
#3     1
#4     2
#5     2
```

If the duplicates are considered based on the equality between adjacent elements, then use `rleid`

```
library(data.table)
df %>% 
    filter(!duplicated(rleid(col.2))) %>% 
    select(col.3 = col.1)
```

---

If we convert to `data.table`, the `unique` also have a `by` option

```
library(data.table)
unique(setDT(df), by = 'col.2')[, .(col.3 = col.1)]
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(col.1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), col.2 = c(1L, 
3L, 7L, 7L, 12L, 14L, 14L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Comment: Thank you @akrun. For some reason, this still fails to give me a complete set of `col.1` values. I will try to add a reproducible example with the real data

Comment: @JKO Please check if your values have either trailing/leading spaces if it is character class

Comment: @JKO Also, please use `dput` for showing the data as it will give the structure of your data

Comment: I am not sure what you mean

Comment: @JKO I meant `dput(head(yourdata))` and copy/paste the output so that I can replicate your issue

Comment: When I use `dput` it returns lists of comma separated values with the suffix "L"

Comment: @JKO What do you get if you do `dput(head(mtcars))` .  Just copy the output.  I  can create the same `df` by using that output

Comment: > dput(head(data))
structure(list(col.1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), col.2 = c(1L, 
3L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 14L)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: @JKO If I use your `data`, I get `data.frame(col3. = data$col.1[!duplicated(data$col.2)])
  col3.
1     1
2     1
3     1
4     1` i.e.  four 1's in col.3

Comment: It works at the beginning of the dataset, but there is a lot more data that I did not include above. I will try to upload it here

Comment: @JKO Do you expect `data.frame(col3. = data$col.1[!duplicated(data$col.2)])$col3.
[1] 1 1 1 1`

Comment: @JKO Just wanted to understand how you are treating duplicates.  Is it based on adjacent elements or `c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1)` what do you expect for unique here

Comment: @JKO Can you try `df %>% 
    filter(!duplicated(rleid(col.2))) %>% 
    select(col.3 = col.1)`

Comment: I am not sure. What I need is a column that is filled with the `col.1` value corresponding to every unique `col.2` value. Part of my problem is that I do not know the correct syntax

Comment: @JKO The codes I showed does exactly what you showed as expected.  if you can dput an example where it doesn't work, then it would be great

Comment: my apologies! It does work! My mistake was that I was also running code that I had designed to stitch together `col.3` with the unique values from `col.2` (which I obtained using `col.4 <- count(data,'col.2')`) . When I do that using `cbind(col.4, col.3)` I get a truncated version of `col.3`

Comment: @JKO Thank you for confirming

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207431/discussion-between-jko-and-akrun).